# Calculating accuracy of train and testing data set

Tags: r, gaussian

I'm confused while calculating train data prediction and test data prediction since the values of each feature is being calculated as same and test accuracy is not so accurate

```
library(dbplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
```

Placeholder for test & train accuracy

```
    train_Data_prediction=rep(1,100)
    test_Data_prediction=rep(1,100)
```

Execute 100 times and later average the accuracy

```
    for(count in c(1:100))
    {
      data_train <- read.csv("parktraining.csv",FALSE,",")
      data_train = as.matrix(data_train)
      x_index=ncol(data_train)

      data_Without_lable <- data_train[,-x_index]
      lable <- data_train[,x_index]

      Train_mean = apply(data_Without_lable,2,mean)
      Train_sd = apply(data_Without_lable,2,sd)

      Train_offsets <- t(t(data_Without_lable) - Train_mean) 
      Train_scaled_data  <- t(t(Train_offsets) / Train_sd)

      positive_ids = which(data_train[,x_index] == 1)
      negative_ids = which(data_train[,x_index] == 0)

      positive_data = Train_scaled_data[positive_ids,]
      negative_data = Train_scaled_data[negative_ids,]

      pos_Mean = apply(positive_data,2,mean)
      positive_sd=apply(positive_data,2,sd)

      neg_Mean = apply(negative_data,2,mean)
      negative_sd=apply(negative_data,2,sd)

      tested_data <- read.csv("parktesting.csv",FALSE,",")
      tested_data = as.matrix(tested_data)

      testing_data = tested_data[,-x_index]

      predict=function(testing_data_row){
      target=0;
```

## Used dnorm() function for normal distribution and calculate probability

```
        p_pos=sum(log(dnorm(testing_data_row,pos_Mean,positive_sd)))
          +log(length(positive_ids)/length(lable))
    p_neg=sum(log(dnorm(testing_data_row,neg_Mean,negative_sd)))+log( 1 - 
          (length(negative_ids)/length(lable)))

    if(p_pos>p_neg){
      target=1
    }else{
      target=0
    }  
}

  test_mean = apply(testing_data,2,mean)
  test_sd = apply(testing_data,2,sd)

  test_offset <- t(t(testing_data) - test_mean)
  test_scaled_data <- t(t(test_offset) / test_sd)

  test_prediction <- apply(test_scaled_data,1,predict)
  target=tested_data[,x_index]
  target

  test_Data_prediction[count]=length(which((test_prediction == target)==TRUE))/length(target)
  test_Data_prediction

  #Predict for train data ( optional, output not printed )
  train_prediction =apply(Train_scaled_data,1,predict)

  train_Data_prediction[count]=length(which((train_prediction == lable)==TRUE))/length(lable)
 }

test_Data_prediction
train_Data_prediction


print(paste("Average Train Data Accuracy:",mean(train_Data_prediction)*100.0,sep = " "))
print(paste("Average Test Data Accuracy:",mean(test_Data_prediction)*100.0,sep = " "))
```

Comment: can you reduce the code to the relevant part and elaborate on what you mean by "since the values of each feature is being calculated as same and test accuracy is not so accurate"?

Comment: we don't have your data, we can't see your output..